# PHP Array_merge not adding comma

Tags: php, arrays, plotly.js

I am building metrics graphs using plotly.js and I am building a grouped bar chart. [image: What my graph looks like]

Each bar in the different groups represents data for a different year. Not all groups have data for every year so I need to have a different structure for each group. For this particular question I need an array of my data to look like this

`[633, 0, 0, 113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

I have got two separate sql queries pulling the 633 and the 113. I then create two different arrays by doing this

```
$array1 = array($value1, array_fill(1, 2, 0)); 
$array2 = array($value2, array_fill(4, 9, 0));
```

I then merge the two arrays together to create one array that my data can be sent to the graph.

```
$finalArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

which produces the result:

[image]

which looks right as far as the data and the order. However, I'm not sure why my values from the database don't have a key to go with the value and the bigger problem is that where the arrays merge a comma is missing so the value 113 is showing up in the wrong group of bars in my chart.

As plotly is a javascript library I am posting the results I am getting when I send the data to the javascript file. I am sending the PHP data to javascript by returning the array variable out of the PHP function and then calling that variable in my javascript file.

```
var finalArray = <? echo json_encode($courseData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
```

So I'm hoping I can get some insight as to why the comma is missing and/or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `array_merge()` produces an array but you're showing JavaScript source. How are you getting from the former to the latter? Is your PHP code outputting JavaScript code? Returning JSON in an AJAX hit?

Comment: Oh, ya I'll edit my post. To answer your question though I have the array_merge in a function and so I return the array variable and then outside of the function I set another variable to call the function. Then in my javascript file I have a line that looks like this ``` var finalArray = <? echo json_encode($courseData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>; ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This builds an array where the first element is a single value and the second element is another array:

```
array($value1, array_fill(1, 2, 0))
```

I.e., you get this:

```
[633, [0, 0]]
```

If you want this output:

```
[633, 0, 0, 113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then you need to build the array with a bunch of single values. You can do this by sending multiple arrays to array_merge(), which will extract the values and then stack them all back together in one array:

```
$new = array_merge(
    [$value1],
    array_fill(1, 2, 0)
    [$value2],
    array_fill(4, 9, 0)
);
```

I'm not sure what "comma is missing" means.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a multidimensional array with `array($value1, array_fill(1, 2, 0));` when you want a single one. You're making an array with the first value that has your number, and second value is an array:

```
(
  [0] => 633
  [1] => Array
  (
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
   )
)
```

Array merge will then put those two multidimensional arrays together to the result you're currently getting.

You'll want something like this:

```
$finalArray = array_merge(
  [$value1],
  array_fill(1, 2, 0)
  [$value2],
  array_fill(4, 9, 0)
);
```

Also, should that 4 be a 3?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 7.4, you can also unpack the `array_fill` results when you create the first two arrays.

```
$array1 = array($value1, ...array_fill(1, 2, 0)); 
$array2 = array($value2, ...array_fill(4, 9, 0));
```

Then the `array_merge` will work as is.

Or (unless you need `$array1` and `$array2` for something else) you can just build the final array the same way without `array_merge`.

```
$finalArray = [$value1, ...array_fill(1, 2, 0), $value2, ...array_fill(4, 9, 0)];
```

If you're not using PHP 7.4... never mind. :-)